# Facebook Feed Dialog without link parameter not working. Error 100

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-apps

With 'link' parameter its working. But without 'link' parameter its not working

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=145634995501895&redirect_uri=https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer&ref=web&display=popup

But the issue is facebook api reference saying its optional. "The link attached to this post. With the Feed Dialog, people can also share plain text status updates with no content from your app; just leave the link parameter empty."

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.5#params

Any one know a solutions for this?